# What does DSolve`DsolveLaplaceTransformDump` mean in solution of DSolve?

Tags: differential-equations, bugs

**Bug introduced in 11.2 or earlier, fixed in 12.2 or earlier.**

---

Reported to Wolfram with CASE number **4028951**

---

on 11.3,

```
ClearAll[u,x,t];
eqn=D[u[x,t],t]+u[x,t]*D[u[x,t],x]==0;
bc=u[0,t]==0;
ic=u[x,0]==x;
sol=DSolve[{eqn,bc,ic},u[x,t],x,t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

What does, terms that have

```
     DSolve`DsolveLaplaceTransformDump`
```

mean in the solution? It looks like DSolve starting using the Laplace method to solve the above PDE. But is the above answer meant to be the final answer, or did `DSolve` gave up in the middle and these `Dump` messages are left there?

Comment: It's a context that's used by internal functions.  Usually, the answer is rewritten in terms of user variables. Happens on 11.2, too. I don't think it should happen.

Comment: That's a bug, please report it. The *Dump* context should never leak.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bug is fixed in *v12.2* or earlier, now `DSolve` returns unevaluated:

[image]

It's a bit sad that `DSolve` still cannot solve the problem.